# Does Azure AI Search Integrated Vectorization use a Vector Database in it's process?

Tags: vector-database, azure-ai-search

I Utilized Azure's AI Search integrated vectorization tool to vectorize my PDFS. I noticed it stored them in Storage accounts as JSON objects that you can view to see each chunk that is vectorized and it's associated vector. My question is, is their a vector database that stores each vector, something that's a UI that I can view the data instead of manually going in each folder to look at each json object? Does this Integrated vectorization method not use a Vector database like Pinecone, and if not is their any benefit to storing it in one?

Sorry if I missed anything, I am relatively new to this. But I had an additional question, I am running into a timeout error when running this service on PDF files that are 50+ pages long. I've been told that I would need to use Langchain or Semantic kernal to break down the files into smaller files then chunks it, is this because in the chunking phase in the integrated vectorization there's a limit to the amount of chunks it can create from 1 PDF? I read that there's a limit to the chunk size, but if i'm not hitting that maximum for each chunk why would it time out?

I am not understanding the use for a vector database if using Azure AI Search integrated vectorization, or just in general using Azure AI Search as a RAG method for vectors

Answer (score 1):

To benefit the community, sharing my suggestions from your [Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1524418/does-azure-ai-search-integrated-vectorization-use).

Azure AI search is a vector database. Based on my understanding of your question, if you do not want to use the API or Search Explorer you may use a UI like the following samples:

[chat-with-your-data-solution-accelerator](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/chat-with-your-data-solution-accelerator)

[azure-search-openai-demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo)

For integrated vectorization -  the actual vectors and content are stored in a search index for quick searching, it uses a storage account as a data source, not to search over. The JSON files you might be looking at is external state.

Kindly checkout this doc for more info:

-[Integrated vectorization - Azure AI Search | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/vector-search-integrated-vectorization)

-[Vectors in Azure AI Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/vector-search-integrated-vectorization)